# Wordpress - template category give me two catogories instead of one

Tags: wordpress

I use the category template for categories. In this template, I use the function get_the_category() at the beginning for show the selected category in a list.

For most of my categories, I don't have any problems, but for two of them (ID 9 and ID 152), on their respective pages, the function give me two categories instead of one (the 9 and the 152).

Have you any idea to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper behavior of [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/):

> Return: (array) Array of objects, one for each category assigned to the post.

If you need to target only one, you can target the first element of the array, like any other array:

```
$cats = get_the_category();  // Get all of the categories
$cat = $cats[0];  // Get one category
```

Comment: Yes I know, but in a category page, the function return only one category (in an array, yes, but only one) EXCEPT for the categories 9 and 152 where the function return 2 categories, and in the same order.
And with your code, it's always the same category (the 152) in first place.

Comment: You need to post your code. How do you expect to choose between the two categories if there are more than one?

Comment: It's not that I don't want to post my code, butin the template, I just have the function get_the_category, that's all.

Comment: The problem is that with two different URL, conencted to two different categories, Wordpress give me the same couple of categories in the two pages.